# Proof concering closed sets, is it correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to show that $A=[a,\infty)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have written: We claim that the compliment $(-\infty,a)$ is open. Note that $A\subset E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a-n, a)$, for an n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n >a$  which is open. Therefore $A$ itself is closed.

Comment: $A$ is not a subset of $E$.

Comment: There is no need for the phrase "for an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\gt a$."

Answer (score 1):

Set $a\in\mathbb R$. We claim that $(-\infty,a)$ is an open set of $\mathbb R$. To prove this, fix $r\in(-\infty,a)$. Now, you can find a positive distance $\delta$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset(-\infty,a)?$

Of course yes, just let 
$$\delta=\frac{a-r}{2}$$
and prove that for all $x$, if $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ it follows that $x\in(-\infty,a)$.